# Node.js combining Mongoose and Sails Waterline

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, sails.js

I'm working on an Open Source microservice based project in Node.js.

### Description of the problem

Some microservices are so thin and only interact with MongoDB, so I haven't used Sails there and preferred using Mongoose directly. Thus, I've implemented mongoose schemas for each of the objects I need to persist in mongo.

I'm also going to have Sails.js in some other microservices, Therefore I'll have to implement Waterline-type schemas for the objects I want to persist & query there.

The problem is the duplication of schemas, which I find useless.

### Solutions I thought of

I wish to use one type of schemas across all the services.

There are 3 options now:

1. A magic method to connect between the schemas (which I'm not aware of), and have both worlds work simultaneously (least probable option).
2. To use Waterline across all the microservices, whether I use Sails.js or not, therefore have 1 schema type in the system.
3. To force Sails.js to use mongoose adapter instead of Waterline, and then implement some CRUD Data Access Layer (DAL) which uses Mongoose internally, and  use it everywhere to access the DB.
   Therefore the Mongoose schemas will be across all the system. But then I give up on the Waterline encapsulation capabilities, and if in the future I'd like to change DB, I'll be in trouble.

I could also compromise and duplicate schemas in my app, but that's the last resort as I believe there has to be some solution to this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whoever consider Waterline vs Mongoose... right to this date, choose Mongoose.

Waterline made us so much head-ache, while mongoose is so smooth and straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

I could think of the following to go fully Sails:

- put the common parts, like the Sails models, in a Sails project and push it to a (private) npm package
- use https://github.com/tjwebb/marlinspike or other sails hooks to import them in every instance you need it.

I have not tried this, but preparing for similar steps in the future.

Also, I saw this issue: https://github.com/tjwebb/marlinspike/issues/4

Comment: I don't understand how marlinspike will help me. To import them in every instance I need is easy - I do npm install my-models-package everywhere...

Comment: In the bottom line I'll have to use Waterline in all the projects without sails, is that what you mean?

Comment: Sorry, yes. That is what I would recommend

Comment: Here is example project for standalone implementation of Waterline ORM: https://github.com/aishwarydhare/standalone-waterline-orm.git